# Way to access huge content from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, browser, datatable

I need to fetch huge data(may be some 10K records) from DB and show it as report(i use DataTable), and it has data filter/search and pagination.

**Question** - which one is best/recommended way from the below option,

1. - I will fetch all the records at once and store it in front end(as a object) and if filter applies i will filter from the object and display it.
   - Likewise i wont interact with DB if i work with pagination(Since i have all the records with myself already)
2. - Every time i need to contact the DB when i applies filter/search.
   - Likewise for pagination,
     For example, if i select page 5 then i will send a query to DB to get me only those data and display it. Note: Number of record per page is also the option to select.

If we have any other best way, please guide me.

Thanks,

Comment: 10k rows is not a lot. format as json and feel free to download the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks @Skarlinski , So do you have any idea about till how much records we can follow this way..? i.e downloading entire data to front end. since i am suspecting whether it may affects the browser's performance

Comment: but how many columns do you need??

Comment: Consider the average web page size is currently around 1.7MB. How big is your report data?
If you render tens of thousands of rows as DOM elements, you are not going to have a fun time

Comment: Hopefully datatable library will not render all of the rows immediatly and will only create them when needed

Comment: @Vanojx1 it contains 6 columns per record

Comment: What is relevant is what is in each record and not how many records you have. The size of the created JSON will be a better tool for estimation. Each column could be a single digit, or the the whole of encyclopedia britannica

Comment: To summarize, I feel this is about testing and getting a feel, knowing what kind of user devices you will have to serve, balancing server costs with user experience and many other factors. But all in all, anything below ~1MB is not a lot of data to store on client machine. You can also consider allowing the creation of csv/excel files on the server side.

Comment: Keep in mind, the part which is most vulnerable for performance is if the whole grid is rendered, creating tens of thousands of html elements]

Comment: @skarlinski thats true :)

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with DataTable, but it appears to be similar to jqGrid, which I'm familiar with.

I prefer your proposed solution #2. You are better off fetching only what you need. If you're only displaying, say, 100 rows, it's wasteful (both in terms of bandwidth and local memory usage) to fetch 10k rows at once if you're only displaying 100.

Use LIMIT on the MySQL side to fetch only the records you need. If you want, say, records 200 through 300 for page 3, you'd add [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) 200, 100 to the end of your query (the first parameter to LIMIT says "start at 200" and the second says "fetch 100 rows.") If DataTable works like jqGrid, you should be able to re-query the database and repopulate your table when the user changes pages, and this fetch will be done in the background with AJAX, which conserves bandwidth. Your query will be identical except for the range specified by the LIMIT at the end of your query.

Think of it this way: say you use GMail and you never archive your messages, so your inbox contains 20,000 emails, but only shows 100 per page. Do you think Google has designed the GMail front-end so that all 20k subject and from lines are fetched at once and stored locally, or is the server queried again when the user changes pages? (It's the latter.)

Comment: This is not a one size fits all solution. i.e how long does it take the DB to fetch results? is the server side processing more expensive etc.

Comment: It may not be one size fits all, but it's generally accepted as a better practice for large record sets. Say the table grows from 10k to 50k rows. Using LIMIT ensures that no matter how large the table gets, fetching the data will use a reasonably consistent and predictable amount of bandwidth, and LIMIT will not slow down the query whatsoever (although as the table grows the query may take longer - this is true whether you use LIMIT or not.)

Comment: I had a same idea as @MatteoC mentioned above.. however i am in confused state to select the right path to go.. So planned for open discussion. As i mentioned above, i am going to show the report from DB record, To be frank i am not sure how far the records grow up in production.. May be it can reach lacks of records..

Comment: 1. Users hate waiting for data to load from server. Big databases with complex queries may take 10 seconds or more, no user will wait that long for pagination, ever. 
2. Bandwidth-  We may be talking here about hundreds of Kb's at most, this is less than a web image.